# Personal Pronoun Usage

Tags: pronouns

> It had been him and Nina that had decided years ago. Now it was her who had to clean up their mess.

or

> It had been he and Nina that had decided years ago. Now it was she who had to clean up their mess.

Which is correct

Comment: If you say "It is he" then use the second choice (this is the classical choice).  If you say "It is him" then use the first choice (this is the more common choice nowadays).